# Google Analytics download event goals not tracked

Tags: google-analytics

I set up some Event goals that are not tracked.

For example I have some documents to download on my page. I have been clicking on them for a few days, yet all goals show 0 conversions.

```
Category: Equals to: Docs
Action: Equals to: Download
Label: Equals to: Best practices
```

Here is the onClick event in the code:

```
<a href="/Docs/Best-Practices.pdf" target="_blank" class="dl" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Docs', 'Download', 'Best practices',, null]);">Best practices</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/Docs/Best-Practices.pdf" target="_blank" class="dl" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Docs', 'Download', 'Best practices']);">Best practices</a>
```

(neither of them works)

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are your events showing up in real-time reports? Have you used a tool like GA Debugger to monitor the tracking beacon getting sent into GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are using the newer Universal Analytics? Then the syntax is different then the Classic Analytics.

Classic Analytics uses gaq.push:

```
<a href="/Docs/Best-Practices.pdf" target="_blank" class="dl" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Docs', 'Download', 'Best practices']);">Best practices</a>
```

Universal Analytics uses a different one, as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#implementation):

> You can also send events using the following convenience commands. In each command, the optional parameters have been removed.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label');
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);  // value is a number.
```

So your example would look something like this:

```
<a href="/Docs/Best-Practices.pdf" target="_blank" class="dl" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Docs', 'Download', 'Best practices');">Best practices</a>
```

Also, to find out if the tracking code you have installed, search for ga.js for Classic Analytics or analytics.js for Universal Analytics.

Comment: I am using //www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js. I changed the code to your suggested one, now waiting for the results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a goal based on the event, it could be a problem with how the event is set up, or how the goal is defined.  Looking at your code and set-up, I don't see any obvious problem.

To debug, check first to see if you are getting events by looking in Behavior >> Events >> Overview.  If you are getting events, then it should look something like this.

[image: events overview]

If you are getting events, then look at Conversions >> Goals >> Overview and see if you are getting any goal conversions.

Sometimes it takes a while for event based goals to show up in GA - at least that has been my experience.  I've seen it take as long as 48 hours.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. In Behavior >> Events >> Overview I am not getting any events. Nothing.